# Codeigniter Active Record bug?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just don't understand, I have code like this:

```
$this->ci->db->select('liked_posts, liked_comments');       
$q = $this->ci->db->get_where('users_fav', array('usr_id' => $this->_usrId));
$result = $q->result_array();
```

And when I, as always, tried to put it into foreach loop.. it's just didn't work.. Because in $result I've got and array where 2 more arrays where stored (table fields)
so to work in foreach loop it would look like this:

```
foreach($result[0] as $value)
```

not:

```
foreach($result as $value)
```

And I was looking for my mistake very long.. Maybe I really did something wrong... Or is it a bug?

**edit:**
print_r($result);

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [liked_posts] => a:0:{}
            [liked_comments] => a:0:{}
        )

)
```

**edit2:**

But shoudn't it be like this:

```
Array
            (
                [liked_posts] => a:0:{}
                [liked_comments] => a:0:{}
            )
```

?? Or I'm starting to go crazy???

**edit3:**
My bad... I realized now... I'm just going crazy.. too much work done today... better go sleep :D Sorry guys

Comment: please post print_r($result) in the code.we want to see it.

Comment: of course, here you got

Comment: define 'does not work', is there an error? The printed `$result` looks like what is to be expected...

Comment: what output you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `$result = $q->result_array();` you will get a multidimentional array as you have now.:

```
foreach( $resuls as $key => $each ){
    echo "result : ".$each['column_name'];
}
```

but if you have just a single row fetched you would likely use `$result = $q->row_array();` which will return a single dimentional array. And you can directly use like this:

```
echo $results['column_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

so you can do this

```
foreach($result as $value)
{
    echo $value['fav_posts'];
}
```

no problem with that.